# platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js - 404 in Angular4/angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js - 404  in Angular4/angular2

before the url business will be comes.

```
 "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:13244/business/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
```

actual url is

```
http://localhost:13244/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
```

How to fix this error:??

The error is:

```
"(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:13244/business/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
```

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI for your project?

Comment: no i am using visual studio